# Save mongodb to different partition

Tags: mongodb, centos6

I've got a mongod instance running on centos6.
I wanted to make sure to have it save everything to /dev/sda2 since last time I was using mongo I ran into my partition cap and had to perform several messy operations to increase partition size.

So, how would I make sure that mongod will save into /dev/sda2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move `/var/lib/mongodb` to other location (possibly `/mnt/sda2/mongodb`) and create symlink from `/var/lib/mongodb` to this new location. Works for me perfectly.

You can also just move and symlink individual data files.

Of course MongoDB must be stopped before doing any of this.

Comment: Good answer, I've also learned that I can check where files and folders are mounted by using the mount command. I didn't have anything in my mongodb yet but after a few tries the link's there now and it works.